# Gitlab DIND Runner TLS Failure

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Im trying to setup a gitlab runner with dind, to build docker images in Gitlab CI Pipelines, but im getting the following errors each build:

```
*** WARNING: Service runner-project-2-concurrentdocker-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-project-2-concurrentdocker-0-wait-for-service" timeout
Health check container logs:
Service container logs:
2021-10-12T14:12:26.652132966Z time="2021-10-12T14:12:26.651911909Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
2021-10-12T14:12:26.653211174Z time="2021-10-12T14:12:26.653132075Z" level=warning msg="could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found"
2021-10-12T14:12:26.653320513Z time="2021-10-12T14:12:26.653240584Z" level=warning msg="Binding to IP address without --tlsverify is insecure and gives root access on this machine to everyone who has access to your network." host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
2021-10-12T14:12:27.653863417Z time="2021-10-12T14:12:27.653434622Z" level=warning msg="Binding to an IP address without --tlsverify is deprecated. Startup is intentionally being slowed down to show this message" host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
```

My Gitlab Runner config.toml looks like this:

```
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab-runner-docker"
  url = "https://gitlab.my.host/"
  token = "MYTOKEN"
  executor = "docker"
  environment = ["DOCKER_DRIVER=overlay2", "DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2375/", "DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR="]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:dind"
    privileged = true
    [[runners.docker.services]]
      name = "docker:dind"
      command = ["--registry-mirror", "http://192.168.1.21"]
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/certs/client", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

There are mysterious bug reports and user questions on those errors, but non of them seem to fix my problem. I tried removing the `tls_verify` settings, and setting the     `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""` CI Pipeline variable and what not. Is there any chance to get those runners booting up fast again with or without tls verification?

Comment: Possible workaround that always works for me is to install Docker on the runner machine and share docker.sock as a volume to the runner container. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding Than you don't need docker:dind, tls certificates and any other services or env variables. Clean and simple.